# How can I get ViewChildren of a Directive when it is inside an ngIf with async pipe

Tags: angular

I have a component that renders its content based on an observable with async pipe.

```
<div *ngIf="equipment$ | async as equipment">
  <button myDirective></button>
</div>
```

In the .ts file, I'm getting all of the MyDirective children. There can be any number.

```
@ViewChildren(MyDirective) actions!: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

And then I want to access it in the ngAfterViewInit.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log(this.actions)
}
```

this logs a QueryList with 0 items. If I put the directive outside of my async pipe it all works perfectly:

```
<div *ngIf="equipment$ | async as equipment">
  // Some HTML here
</div>
<button myDirective></button>
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the directives nested under the async pipe? I need to keep the ngIf because I have inputs bound to the equipment variable (which contains properties).

EDIT:

So, after thinking and thinking, I realized that what I'm trying to do here is to re-create NgRx. After all this time thinking it was too complicated, I now understand all the benefits it brings and the problems it solves. I'm gonna go ahead and try implementing it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hide directive, let me expain it:

```
    @Input() hide: boolean;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.hide) {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'visibility', 'visible');
    }
}
```

since the hide directive will not display the element on the dom but it can still be accesible

Comment: Yes, this is something I could be doing, but then it would cause other errors since I have NgModels bound to attributes of my equipment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simon, You can not access to an element that it's not in the screen when you execute an instruction.

Of course you can not access in afterViewInit because the condition is yet false. So, you has two aproach

1. Create an observable based in yours and use rxjs operator tap

   ```
   equipmentDone$=this.equipment$.pipe(
      tap((res:any)=>{
         ..here you has yet your this.actions...
         //it's possible, I'm not pretty sure you need enclosed in a setTimeout
         setTimeout(()=>{
             ..here sure, sure you has this.actions..
         })
      })
   )
   ```

   And use

   ```
   <div *ngIf="equipmentDone$ | async as equipment">
     <button myDirective></button>
   </div>
   ```
2. Subscribe to the observable [changes](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#properties) of the QueryList

   ```
   ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.actions.changes.subscribe(res=>{
        ..here you has your actions..
     })
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `static: false` since it's a dynamically rendered component:

```js
@ViewChildren(MyDirective, { static: false }) actions!: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

but you won't be sure that the directive will be available in ngAfterView init. because `equipment$`can take some time...

maybe you can add a `tap()` in the observable and do your `console.log()` there istead

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `static: false` property on ViewChildren, only on ViewChild. And even then, this is not fixing the issue, I tried it with the `static: false` and a ViewChild, I can't access the directive in ngAfterViewInit because the observable subscription is not back yet so equipement is null and my directive is not rendered.

The tap solution might do it though I will try it. Even though it will be a bit akward because the real code I want to do is a combineLatest, not a console.log.

Comment: well the other solution is not to use the async pipe but to subscribe manually in ngOnInit